# Class member of a class is garbage collected even though the Application has a reference to it

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I'm seeing a behavior that I wasn't expecting regarding garbage collection on Android.

I have a class that extends Application named App and modified the manifest so that

<application
        android:name=".App" ...

I've used this before to be able to get the Application context through a static method for convenience but also store small but crucial information that should only be garbage collected when the entire application is. This information is stored in a singleton object that is initialized and a reference stored in the application class:

```
public class App extends Application {

Context mContext;
Info info;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = this;

    info = Info.getInstance();

    this.setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
}

public static Context getContext(){
    return mContext;
}
}
```

When Info is initialized, a simple member object is initialized as well:

```
public class Info {


    public Profile profile;

    (...)

    private Info() {
       profile = new Profile();
    }

    (...)
 }
```

The issue that I've experienced, when the App is paused and I run another memory intensive app (to force garbage collection), when I return to the App, I get a NullPointerException when trying to access the profile var

Info.getInstance().profile

Shouldn't the fact that the Application holds a reference to the "Info" singleton and the fact that the singleton holds a reference to "profile" keep it from getting garbage collected?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: GC can't collect object if you have hard reference to. Your code have a bug somewhere not related to GC. Show more code )

Comment: Change it to : private Profile profile;

Comment: @Leonidos : I thought the same for a long time, but I've gone through the code and I haven't found any other explanation other than GC. I'll have a look again later. Thanks!

Comment: @martinezpt this cant be true ) show us all your code and line where you get error and logcat.

Comment: @Leonidos I've just fixed the issue. The entire Application was being garbage collected (as I know it could happen). The problem was that when it was recreated, the process was slightly different from a normal startup, because the `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` was restoring some views that during the normal startup were only created after some initialization had happened. This caused some references in those restored views to count on content that simply wasn't there yet.

Comment: @Leonidos  In the end you were right, since it wouldn't make sense for the Object to be garbage collected on its own. If you'd like to change your comment into an answer, I'd gladly accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Never mind ) I glad that you fixed it.
Android can destroy application instance and kill your process any time if it is in background.

Answer (score 0):

Get to know more about application lifecycle in android. If you start another app that needs memory, other applications are killed in background.

Then OnCreate should be run once again, so it can't be garbage collector, because Info will be created once again from start.

[Activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: That's why I have the object in the Application class, so that it remains for the lifetime of the Application or gets recreated if the whole Application is killed (not only the activities).

Answer (score -1):

**Singleton** means only one object will be instantiated, there is no relation of garbage collection with singleton, see this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979023/why-are-there-java-singleton-classes-when-would-you-need-to-use-one) for better understanding of [**singleton**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979023/why-are-there-java-singleton-classes-when-would-you-need-to-use-one)

see this answer of how you can store data locally [How to store data in app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6501843/519718)