# discussion on sharedpreferences

Tags: android, eclipse

I am studying Android development for *Sams Android Development in 24 hours*. I am implementing a game called theredone that contains the following activities:

`quizactivity`, `splashactivity`, `gameactivity`, `menuactivity`, `settingsactivity`, `helpactivity`. `splashactivity` extends `quizactivity` while `quizactivity` extends `Activity`.

I implemented `SharedPreferences` in `quizactivity.java`.

```
package com.androidbook.triviaquiz6;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES = "GamePrefs";

    private SharedPreferences myPrefs; //Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token -//----------------------------


   myPrefs = Actionactivity.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit(); 
   prefsEditor.putString("key name", "key valuse"); 
   prefsEditor.commit(); 


   //this one to read data  
    myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE); 

    myPrefs.getString("key name", "") ;
}//Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody -----------------------
```

could you help me out please i dont think its a dumb qs

Comment: Very related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243080/i-would-like-others-to-help-me-on-sharedpreferences; please please pick up a good Java book & tutorial, you're missing the basics.

Comment: Might be the number in your package name. Oh an the fact your missing the Android Activity lifecycle methods!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below code as reference for shared preference::::And in your code you dont have oncreate method

```
//Retrive value from SharedPreference
SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES , android.content.Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
String value =  preferences.getString(key, null);


//Save value in SharedPreference
SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES , android.content.Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();
```

Updated:::

```
package com.androidbook.triviaquiz6;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES = "GamePrefs";
    private SharedPreferences myPrefs;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....

    //this one data set in SharedPreferences file

    myPrefs = Actionactivity.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString("ket name", "key valuse");
    prefsEditor.commit();

    }
}
```

Comment: how do i use oncreate method. i ask that because in res\layout i dont have any @string in .xml. i have splash.xml,menu.xml,game.xml,scores.xml,settings.xml,help.xml. how do i use oncreate.

Comment: which space you are saying about

Comment: i was able to do it:     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243080/i-would-like-others-to-help-me-on-sharedpreferences

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the `Actionactivity` activity in the `QuizActivity` activity.
Actionactivity is not instantiate yet and your are opening a `getSharedPreferences` using that.

getSharedPreferences method is of context method and for current activity you can refer the `this` instance to call this `getSharedPreferences` method.

If you don't wan't to use activity's context then you can use the `application context` by calling `getApplicationContext()`.

For more information about preference you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5950109/630668)