# SharedPreferences with OnCreate

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to achieve a goal which is adding some kind of wizard like this:

App launches for the first time > User follows wizard > Final wizard step saves some data into the SharedPreferences and continues to the activity that the user choosed > App Quits > App Relaunches > App shows activity that the user choose via the wizard data in `SharedPreferences`.

I know I can save data into the `SharedPreferences` space but how should I achieve this.

The user gets to see a view via an `Android:OnClick` action.
My App only has 1 main java class with different view actions like this:

```
public void myapp_confirmsetup(View view) {
setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_app_confirmsetup);
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("MyApp", "app_off").commit();    
}
```

I think that from now on I only have to load the string with the `OnCreate` method but I'm unsure how I can do that.
Can someone push me into the right direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use getSharedPreferences in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950043/how-to-use-getsharedpreferences-in-android)

Comment: @Dharmendra No it's not I'm not trying to save login form data.

Comment: You know instead of using a string.. you it makes more sense to use a boolean instead of String.. "My_App_Status" and its value can be true or false.. why use a string if its a binary answer anyways...

Comment: I think using a string is better because I'm not only storing on and off but also which type of activity the user decided (So for example firstoption_on,firstoption_off,secondoption_on,secondoption_off).

Comment: thats bad.. bad by design.. you should change it so that it makes more sense. First_Option_State | True or false .. Second_Option_State | True or False. When designing your preferences you should try to be as clear as possible, just because you can doesn't mean you should. There are always better ways to approach these kinds of things. Also constantly comparing objects (Strings) as compared to primitives is not efficient. Its wasted CPU cycles if you don't have to do it.

Comment: Since I'm a beginning Android developer I'm unsure how to achieve that, do you have any example I should try?

Comment: There is a ton of information that is available on the dev site, just look up shared preferences. Also, I'm sure there are enough tutorials on the internet (use google) that go over this. Also make sure you know java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  final SharedPreferences pref1 = getSharedPreferences("myapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
  String str1= pref1.getString("Stringval", null);
if(str1.equals("app_off")){
   //do something
 }else(str1.equals("app_on")){
   //do something else
 }
```

Comment: I think this is the thing I want, this code only gives me one problem: java syntax error misplaced constructs - Do you know why?

Comment: Maybe if you put it onCreate() ?

Comment: Did that already, found another solution based on your answer. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use this to store the string...

```
    final SharedPreferences pref1 = getSharedPreferences("myapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref1.edit();
    editor.putString("Stringval", "xxxxxxx");
    editor.commit();
```

to get the value from SharedPreference use below code:-

```
final SharedPreferences pref1 = getSharedPreferences("myapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
String str1= pref2.getString("Stringval", null);
```

Comment: But I'm already storing data into the SharedPreferences If I'm not mistaking (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("MyApp", "app_off").commit();) I'm looking for something like if string is then load view1 else if string is load view2 is this possible?