# getSharedPreferences Null Pointer Exception on some devices

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am using SharedPreferences to get some saved values. I only get a null pointer exception on some devices. When I test the code in my own device I don't get any problem. But some of my user get the error.

Here is my class to get the value of SharedPreference:

```
public class SavingData {
     public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
     public static MainActivity mainActivity;

public static int getRestTime() {
    // Restore preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = mainActivity.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    int restTime = settings.getInt("resttime", defaultRestTime); // 0 is the default
                                                        // value
    return restTime;
}
```

In my main class I declare the mainActivity variable.

```
  SavingData.mainActivity = this;
```

Here is the error I get:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.playsimple.fitnessapp/com.playsimple.fitnessapp.ExerciseStartActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.playsimple.fitnessapp.data.SavingData.getDifficulty(SavingData.java:91)
>   at
>   com.playsimple.fitnessapp.ExerciseStartActivity.initExercise(ExerciseStartActivity.java:69)
>   at
>   com.playsimple.fitnessapp.ExerciseStartActivity.onCreate(ExerciseStartActivity.java:64)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
>   ComponentInfo{com.playsimple.fitnessapp/com.playsimple.fitnessapp.ExerciseStartActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:647) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.playsimple.fitnessapp.data.SavingData.getDifficulty(SavingData.java:91)
>   at
>   com.playsimple.fitnessapp.ExerciseStartActivity.initExercise(ExerciseStartActivity.java:69)
>   at
>   com.playsimple.fitnessapp.ExerciseStartActivity.onCreate(ExerciseStartActivity.java:64)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)

Comment: `NullPointerException at com.playsimple.fitnessapp.data.SavingData.getDifficulty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an instance of your main activity here:

```
public static MainActivity mainActivity;
```

and then calling shared Prefs.. using that. Get the context object instead from your main activity and then call it.
Also use this including MODE_PRIVATE argument:

```
SharedPreferences userDetails = context.getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

See [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950043/how-to-use-getsharedpreferences-in-android).
Also see the docs for [Context getSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int) )

Comment: Why should I use MODE_PRIVATE? Is it not 0?

Comment: if MODE_PRIVATE is not found use Context.MODE_PRIVATE

Comment: So I should not use static methods and change it to normal methods?

Comment: from whereever you are calling the function, also get the context object, getRestTime(Context context), then context.getSharedPreferences(...). About the static thing i do not know if it should be used or not. But variable mainActivity seems to be the Problem.

Comment: When I do mainActivity.MODE_PRIVATE I get this warning: "The static field Context.MODE_PRIVATE should be accessed in a static way". Is it safe to do this Context.MODE_PRIVATE?

Comment: yes that should be accesed in a static way, hence use Context.MODE_PRIVATE

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your sharedPreferences from other Activity as,

```
SharedPreferences settings = mainActivity.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: What do you mean by calling from another Activity? Do you mean I should use that instead of SavingData.getRestTime();

Comment: savingData is not an activity in the code that you posted. Since it is a class, using getSharedPreferences with the preference name and  mode should work.