# How do I ask for someone's name then save it on Android?

Tags: java, android

How do I ask someone for their name and then save it into a string (on Android). I tried creating an EditText and saving it into a string, but I can't use that string across all my classes, so then I tried to save it into the internal storage of my phone, but I got a logic error which I couldn't solve, so I just gave up on that. How do I do this? It can be either Java or XML (I prefer XML). Please, any suggestions?

Comment: Please paste the code and the error you got here. That would help identify the issue.

Comment: I'll just leave this here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). But you need a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) to gain access to it, e.g. via the `getSharedPreferences()` method.

So a quick solution (not elegant though) would be to keep a reference to your main activity (or to any other instance of a class that extends Context) in some place that is visible to the whole app (maybe a class named Globals with some public static field) and then retrieve and use the shared preferences from wherever you need via this reference.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5950109/5166645) is an example of how you can set and get the shared preferences.