# SharedPreferences not saving in some Android versions

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

Following is the code I used to save `SharedPreference`:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

editor.putString("deliveryId", obj.get("deliveryId").toString());
editor.commit();
```

This is not working in some devices, but working in some devices. It is working on KitKat but doesn't work on JellyBean and Lollipop.

Following is the code I used to get the data:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String deliveryId = preferences.getString("deliveryId", "0");
```

Always gives the default value, i.e. `0`, on some devices.

Comment: instead of default shared prefs, use a key to get them [in the common way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5950109/4700782)

Comment: Either the `obj.get("deliveryId").toString()` computes to "0" or you need to uninstall previous APK + install a clean build.

Comment: `getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())` AND `.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`. Please tell what kind of contexts you use.

Comment: @irfan. `irfan` ? Can we expect an `IrfanView` for Android ;-)?

Comment: `editor.commit();` Also use `editor.apply();` before.

Answer (score 1):

I think default preference creating problem for you try like below for saving SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("<Pref Name>", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

editor.putString("deliveryId", obj.get("deliveryId").toString());
editor.commit();
```

to get the data:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("<Pref Name>", MODE_PRIVATE);
String deliveryId = preferences.getString("deliveryId", "0");
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Why is this better than **getDefaultSharedPreferences**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky frankly speaking, i do not have exact idea why not to use getDefaultSharedPreferences but you can go through below link for more details 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14359