# In android methods are called without creating Object

Tags: java, android, object

I'm a beginner learning java and andorid
so please bear with me even if the question sounds idiotic.

So from what i know from java,
in order to call a non static method,
class must be initiated.

But i came across a code like below

might not be correct since i'm writing off of my memory

```
SharedPreferences shared = getsharedpreference("i",String)
```

here *getsharedpeference* which is a method inside **ContextWarpper** is called without creating the class. The method seems to be non static, so i am wondering how this is possible?

Comment: How can it be "inside a class" if there's no instance of the class? What makes you think there's no instance of the class this code is from?

Comment: Can you point towards the code where saw this? Your scenario cannot happen because all instance methods need an instance of the class. The android framework code initializes (creates instances) a bunch of things for you - some examples are your application, activities etc.

Comment: Code like that could be called within a method in an `Activity`, and would be the same as calling `this.getSharedPreferences()` (since in that case `this` is a context). Some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9255684/9473786).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is dependent on which `Activity` is being used but they all boil down to the same thing.

`android.app.Activity` extends `android.view.ContextThemeWrapper`

`android.view.ContextThemeWrapper` extends  `android.content.ContextWrapper`

`android.content.ContextWrapper` extends `android.content.Context`

In `android.content.Context` the function

```
public abstract SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences (String name, 
                int mode)
```

exists and it is `public` meaning through inheritance all classes that extend it have access to the function.

Through a series of inheritance `android.app.Activity` can use a function that does not exclusively belong to it.

Comment: ah that's why...now i understand thank you!!